# ASP.NET MVC Routing Maproute parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am just going through on `MVC routing frame work`. I am bit confused on parameter taken by `RouteCollection.MapRoute` method.

If I took a trditional example of below request

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

 - List item

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",                                              // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults
        );

    }

    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }
}
```

It's mapped with following signatures

```
public static Route MapRoute(
    this RouteCollection routes,
    string name,
    string url,
    Object defaults
)
```

My question is regarding "Object defaults" ,

1. Why we are using it as  `new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }`
2. Is this is a fixed format?
3. How can `CLR interpret sequence` of parameter?

Follow up questions:

a. Why we decorate controller,action or id inside a bracket {}?

b. Is there any match in between URL specify and defaults?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc668201(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 3):

> Why we are using it as  new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }

To basically initialize the route with default values. The values you pass into `MapRoute` method transformed into a `IDictionary<string, object>` for later lookup.

```
Is this is a fixed format?
```

No, you can omit or add more values as per your URL. The values that you specify in defaults will be used for lookup.

For example, You can set a route name Search as following:

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Search",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{searchId}",
        defaults: new {controller = "Account", action = "Login", searchId = UrlParameter.Optional}
        );
```

> How can CLR interprt sequenation of parameter?

By adding them into a Dictionary (RouteValueDictionary to be precise).

> a. Why we decorate controller,action or id inside a bracket {}?

Short answer, it is a convention... long answer, as per MSDN, excerpts from [MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc668201(v=vs.100).aspx)

> In a URL pattern, you define placeholders by enclosing them in braces
>   ( { and } ). You can define more than one placeholder in a segment,
>   but they must be separated by a literal value. For example,
>   {language}-{country}/{action} is a valid route pattern. However,
>   {language}{country}/{action} is not a valid pattern, because there is
>   no literal value or delimiter between the placeholders. Therefore,
>   routing cannot determine where to separate the value for the language
>   placeholder from the value for the country placeholder.

```
b. Is there any match in between URL specify and defaults?
```

Yes, the defaults values are for the placeholders in the URL. If you add more default then placeholder, it will be ignored. The default value is used if a value for that parameter is not included in the URL.

For more information, I will point you to this excellent [MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc668201(v=vs.100).aspx).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for quick response it helps a lot.Some more quick question on same

 1. url: "{controller}/{action}/{searchId}"
 Why we decorate controller,action or id inside a bracket {}

 2. Is there any match in bewteen URL specify and defaults?

Comment: I have added your follow up questions in your original question for other readers. Please see my updated answer. By the way did you read the MSDN article? Did you find it useful?

Comment: Yes I go through the link and very usefull.TThanks a lot.

But I am bit confused about {} URL pattern, I have tried "{controller}/{action}" and  "{action}/{controller}" both are working perfectly :)

Comment: Yes, It will work in both cases. Your URL pattern just tell how many placeholders will be there in the incoming request's url after server name. Position does not matter as long as it is present in URL and defaults has value for corresponding placeholder. I suggest try more and you will get it soon.

Comment: @user3886602 - When I get confused with which route will match, I use this tool... http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx/

Answer (score 0):

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Search",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{searchId}",
    defaults: new {controller = "Account", action = "Login", searchId = UrlParameter.Optional},
    new {id = @"\d{1, 2}" }
);
```

Does `new` expression not work for MVC 5 constraints?

Comment: This looks like its a comment that would normally be included in the answer (when you have more rep).  You ill probably get more traction asking this in its own question referencing the posted answer...